# Footer not lining up properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

for some reason my footer doesn't seem to be lining up properly with the full page. 
[image]

i do have the body of the site in a contain class so the bottom of my footer does line up with the the body of the site. However because it it take up 100% of the screen it now pushed the site toward the right by the same amount it was pushed away from the left. I hope that makes sense. I have got my footer outside of the div class however it still seem to act as if it was inside it. My nav bar on the other hand seems to work perfectly taking up the whole screen. Any ideas im very confused.

this is my footer code

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<style>
{% block style %}
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}


{% endblock %}
</style>

<footer class="footer" >
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <p class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</p>
      </div>
</footer>
```

and im then using   `{% include 'footer.html' %}` under `</script>` and inside `</body>` in my base.html

Comment: share html, css code

Comment: @techLove hi sorry just did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using position `absolute` then you have to  set `left: 0` to span full width of page

```
.footer {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   ...
}
```